# asp.net web form textbox

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, textbox

I have a ASP.NET VB WEB Form reading data from a Paradox Security Interface. The reading and displaying the data on the output window is well working but the textbox only shows the text from the btnStart/btnStop sub.
The data are not displayed.

Any suggestion is welcome, thanks in advance, JPB

```
  Imports System.IO.Ports
Imports System.Console
Imports System.Text.Decoder

Public Class frmMain
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Public sp As New SerialPort("COM3", 19200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One)

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Try
            sp.Close()
            sp.WriteTimeout = 10000
            sp.ReadTimeout = 10000
            btnStart.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
            AddHandler sp.DataReceived, AddressOf DataReceivedHandler

        Catch ex As Exception
            txtRead.Text = txtRead.Text & vbCrLf & ex.Message
            If sp.IsOpen = True Then
                sp.Close()
                btnStart.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
            End If
        End Try
    End Sub

    Protected Sub btnStart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click
        Try
            txtRead.Text = txtRead.Text & vbCrLf & "Start"
            sp.Open()
            btnStart.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Green
        Catch ex As Exception
            txtRead.Text = txtRead.Text & vbCrLf & ex.Message
            If sp.IsOpen = True Then
                sp.Close()
                btnStart.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
            End If
        End Try
    End Sub

    Protected Sub btnStop_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStop.Click
        Try
            txtRead.Text = txtRead.Text & vbCrLf & "Stop"
            sp.Close()
            btnStart.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
        Catch ex As Exception
            txtRead.Text = txtRead.Text & vbCrLf & ex.Message
            If sp.IsOpen = True Then
                sp.Close()
                btnStart.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
            End If
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub DataReceivedHandler(sender As Object, e As SerialDataReceivedEventArgs)
        Dim spRead As SerialPort = sender
        Try
            Dim input As String = spRead.ReadExisting
            txtRead.Text = input
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(input)
        Catch ex As Exception
            txtRead.Text = txtRead.Text & vbCrLf & ex.Message
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub onbeforeunload()
        If sp.IsOpen = True Then
            sp.Close()
            btnStart.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: In your Page_Load event you may have to write the code inside `if IsPostBack = False then <your code> End If`

Comment: Hi Vignesh, thank you for the suggestion, but does not resolve the problem. But I have the same app as vb desktop and get now an error message: {"Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'txtRead' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on."}. Perhaps the same problem?